# How to create vector (10^16 + 1, 10^16 + 2, ... , 10^16 + 1000) using R?

Tags: r, precision, mantissa

I would like to create the following vector (10^16 + 1, 10^16 + 2, ... , 10^16 + 1000).
But if I try it like this:

```
daten <- rep(1e+16,1000)
daten + 1:1000
```

It gives me just an approximation:

```
[1] 10000000000000000 10000000000000002 10000000000000004 10000000000000004
[5] 10000000000000004 10000000000000006 10000000000000008 10000000000000008
[9] 10000000000000008 10000000000000010 10000000000000012 10000000000000012
[13] 10000000000000012 10000000000000014 10000000000000016 10000000000000016 
 ......
```

How can I get R to calculate more precise ? 
Thank you

Comment: How much more precise?

Comment: R is not (at least out of the box) an arbitrary precision calculator. In your example you are dealing with floating point arithmetic. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_formats

Comment: @Rich Scriven: so that the last digit is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Rmpfr` package allows you as much precision as you need. Create numbers using the `mpfr` function, specifying the value + the number of bits of precision you need.

```
library(Rmpfr)
daten <- mpfr(1:1000, 120)
daten <- daten + mpfr(1e16, 120)
print(daten[1:5])
```

This yields the following:

```
5 'mpfr' numbers of precision  120   bits 
[1] 10000000000000001 10000000000000002 10000000000000003 10000000000000004 10000000000000005
```